# Is there a way to add files/folders to a tar file?

Tags: linux

Is there a way to add files/folders to a tar file?

I am using the `tar` command for compression.

Answer (score 3):

`tar` doesn't compress anything, but if you want to append to an existing archive, you want the `-r` flag.

Comment: i want to add folder and it wont work

Comment: @nis, I just did a test and it worked fine.  What command line are you using?

Comment: i am using linux and the commands are:
tar -cfz foo.tar.gz nis1/
tar -rfz foo.tar.gz nis/

Comment: @nis, You can't use `-r` on a compressed archive.  Try without the `-z` options.

Answer (score 3):

You can't modify a compressed tarfile. You can append (`-r`) or update (`-u`) an uncompressed archive.